# The Hardy space $\mathbb{H}^{n\times m}_{2}$ in the upper half plane

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given $f\in \mathbb{H}^{1\times m}_{2}(U) $  and  $g\in\mathbb{H}^{m\times m}_{2}(U)$.

Is it true that  $fg\in \mathbb{H}^{1\times m}_{2}(U)$ ??

If not, what conditions needed so that it would be true!

*Is the problem related to the Smirnov maximum principle?

> Where:
>
> $\mathbb{H}^{n\times m}_{2}(U)$ is  the Hardy space of
>   $n\times m$ matrix valued functions with entries in the space
>   $\mathbb{H}_{2}(U)$, in the upper half plane $U$, with norm
>   $$ \|f\|_{\mathbb{H}_{2}^{n\times m}}^{2} = \sup_{y>0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} trace\{f^{*}(x+ iy)f(x+iy)\}\, \mathrm{d}x $$